# Best way to extract information from a Webrequest string

Tags: vb.net

I need to extract from a big string some informations, this string is from a webrequest which I made from this website address http://www.feriados.com.br/feriados-cuiaba-mt.php?ano=2019, I need the holiday name, kind of holiday and the date of it.

I started with this:

```
Inicio = InStr(1, responseFromServer, "onmouseout=""this.style.textDecoration='none';"">")
Tamanho = responseFromServer.Substring(Inicio, Len(responseFromServer) - Inicio).IndexOf("onmouseover=""this.style.textDecoration='underline';""")
Resultado = responseFromServer.Substring(Inicio, Tamanho)
MsgBox(Resultado)
```

But I think there's a better way to do it, without using tons of substring's. But I don't know how.

---

The "responseFromServer" String is like this:

```
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Sexta-feira Santa</a></span></div><li><div id="899732013" title="<b>Feriado Nacional</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_feriados">21/04/2019 - <a href="feriados-nacionais/dia-de-tiradentes.php" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Dia de Tiradentes</a></span></div><li><div id="360309589" title="<b>Feriado Nacional</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_feriados">01/05/2019 - <a href="feriados-nacionais/dia-do-trabalho.php" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Dia do Trabalho</a></span></div><li><div id="707175857" title="<b>Facultativo</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_facultativos">20/06/2019 - <a href="feriados-nacionais/corpus-christi.php" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Corpus Christi</a></span></div><li><div id="1027605336" title="<b>Feriado Municipal</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_feriados">20/06/2019 - <a href="http://www.legisweb.com.br/legislacao/?id=279803" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Corpus Christi</a></span></div><li><div id="628679930" title="<b>Feriado Nacional</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_feriados">07/09/2019 - <a href="feriados-nacionais/independencia-do-brasil.php" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">Independência do Brasil</a></span></div><li><div id="709487216" title="<b>Feriado Nacional</b> " style="display:inline"><span class="style_lista_feriados">12/10/2019 - <a href="feriados-nacionais/nossa-senhora-aparecida.php" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
```

I need to extract from the first line

1. "Sexta-feira Santa"
2. "Feriado Nacional"
3. "21/04/2019"

And the same information from all others lines

Comment: That site [provides an API](http://www.calendario.com.br/api_feriados_municipais_estaduais_nacionais.php) that can return a JSON. Use that instead of an HTML response.

Comment: Awesome Jimi, that's much better what I was doing... Now I've to find a way to extract information from JSON. Do you've any link to help me?

Comment: Install [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (v. `12.0.X+`) available as NuGet Package through your VS NuGet Package Manager. This library is considered the standard to handle JSON structures. Update your question, posting the JSON you get from the API. Note that VS has a Paste Special function, `Paste JSON As Classes`, that lets you convert the JSON structure to .Net standard classes (a Model). More on-line resources provide this kind of service ([JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/), for example, since it creates VB.Net classes)

Comment: I used a XML reader, it worked like a charm. Got the tutorial from this website: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/xmldocument.html

Comment: You should absolutely learn how to use Json.Net. Some JSON structures cannot be deserialized using a XML parser. Custom JSON parsers (that override the standard behaviour) are also often needed. You won't easily (if ever) find corresponding solutions with a XML parser.

Comment: Also, note that using Json.Net (or the equivalent .Net Core 3.0 parser), you can deserialize the whole structure with a single command.